# Fail on loading lat and lng fast

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

The problem is that when the map is load, the latitude and longitude are still null. And then crash the page. It takes some secods to load the variables with the lat and lng. But i cant figure out how to make the map wait until the latitude and longitude are loaded.

I try to use a ternary in the map but didnt work

```
export default function GeolocationMap() {

  
  const paseadores = useSelector((state) => state.paseadores)
 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { user, isAuthenticated } = useAuth0();
  

  
  let usuarioIdRaro = ""
  let id = ""
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    usuarioIdRaro = user.sub
    id = usuarioIdRaro.substring(6)
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getDetalleUsuario(id));
        dispatch(getusers())
        dispatch(getpaseadores())
     
      }, []);

  const contratadosPor = paseadores.filter(({ contratadoPor }) => contratadoPor === id)
  const latitude = contratadosPor && contratadosPor.length > 0 ? contratadosPor.map(({ lat }) => lat) : null;
  const longitude = contratadosPor && contratadosPor.length > 0 ? contratadosPor.map(({ lng }) => lng): null;

  console.log("latlng", latitude)
  console.log("latlng", longitude)

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
   dispatch(getpaseadores())
  }, 1500);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [])


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


  function FlyMapTo() {

    const map = useMap()

    useEffect(() => {
        map.flyTo(position)
        
    }, {enableHighAccuracy: true})

    return null
}


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

const position = latitude && longitude ? [latitude, longitude] : null;

  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////  ///////////////

  return (
    <div className={stl.paginaGps}>
    <NavBar />
    <div className={stl.titulo}>Aqui podras ver la ubicacion del paseador en tiempo real</div>

    <div className={stl.paseador}>
    
    <MapContainer center={position} zoom={16}>
      <FlyMapTo />
      <TileLayer
        url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
      />
      <Marker 
      position={position}
      icon={IconLocationWalker}>
        <Popup>El Paseador se encuentra Aqui</Popup>
      </Marker>
    </MapContainer>
    
    </div>

    <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to check for `latitude` and `longitude` variables, if they are `null`, show a "Loading" component.

The React component will re-render when the values get loaded in your store since you are selecting the `paseadores` variable from there.

Here's how it should look like:

```
const position = latitude && longitude ? [latitude, longitude] : null;

// Right after you calculate position
if (!position) {
  return null
}

OR

if (!position) {
  return <div>Loading...</div>
}

// return your current component here, it will only load if position is not null
```

This would not load the rest of the logic until lat and long are loaded and not null.

Answer (score 0):

im gettin this error still:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'lat')
at Object.project (Projection.SphericalMercator.js:24:1)
at Object.latLngToPoint (CRS.js:28:1)
at NewClass.project (Map.js:982:1)
at NewClass._getNewPixelOrigin (Map.js:1505:1)
at NewClass._move (Map.js:1224:1)
at NewClass._resetView (Map.js:1184:1)
at NewClass.setView (Map.js:206:1)
at MapContainer.js:32:1
at commitAttachRef (react-dom.development.js:23645:1)
at commitLayoutEffectOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:23503:1)
```

Comment: It's not an answer, looks like an update or comment to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I already fix it. I just was getting wrong the latitude and longitude inside an array. So i need the String alone. So i did this and work fine

```
     const contratadosPor = paseadores.filter(({ contratadoPor }) => contratadoPor === id)
const latitude = contratadosPor && contratadosPor.length > 0 ? contratadosPor.map(({ lat }) => lat) : null;
  const longitude = contratadosPor && contratadosPor.length > 0 ? contratadosPor.map(({ lng }) => lng): null;
const latitude1 = latitude[0];
const longitude1 = longitude[0]
```